# Ajax datatable using Laravel 10

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I shortened the code with columns id and action. It's supposed to get all the data from the sales table using ajax but when I run the site `jquery-3.5.1.js:10099     GET http://sample.test/sale.list?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D...404 (Not Found)` shows up with pop up `DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7` warning

```
<!-- table -->
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var sale_url = "{{config('app.url')}}/list/"; // absolute link
        var table = $('.table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ url('sale.list') }}",
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function getSales(Request $request) {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $sales = Sale::orderby('id', 'asc')->select('*')->get();

        return Datatables::of($sales)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
                $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                return $actionBtn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('list', 'SaleController@getSales')->name('sale.list');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `url()` with `route()` and you will be good to go, if you wish to use url() then you've to use like `url("/list/")` or you if you're using any group `prefix` above this route like `sale` then it would be `url("/sale/list")`

Here [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-url) will use the path of route

```
url("/list/")
```

And [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-route) will use name of route

```
route('sale.list')
```

Your ajax function would be like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var table = $('.table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('sale.list') }}",
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error is still the same. Is the controller function `getSales` correct?

Comment: @hackroot please try `php artisan route:cache` and `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: I just did and the error is the same.

Comment: Are you using any prefix above route in web.php ? @hackroot

Comment: `Auth::routes();`
`Route::get('/', 'SaleController@index');`
`Route::post('store', 'SaleController@store')->name('sale.store');`
`Route::get('list', 'SaleController@getSales')->name('sale.list');`
These are all the routes inside web.php

Comment: try `php artisan route:list` and check what is the URI for that list route

Comment: GET|HEAD   list ........................ sale.list › SaleController@getSales

Comment: `http://sample.test/sale.list` is this still happening with your URL ? @hackroot

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. I didn't put `use DataTables;`